# ValidateRequest not working

Tags: asp.net

**Here's the scenario:**

I've got a regular hyperlink on my .ascx.  (no I have decided NOT to use an asp.net control)
That hyperlink when clicked sends over the querystring an ID of an object to be deleted so in the code-behind of my page, I grab that and if it's there call a RemoveSomeItem method which removes it and then does a Response.Redirect back to the Request.Path since we don't know what .aspx page will be using this control.  That all works fine.

But I need to also show a nice message at the top of that .aspx page after redirect "you have just deleted [item name]"

So what I did was in that response redirect, I added an additional querystring param called removedItemName which has for example even some HTML in the string:

```
&removedName=<sup>©</sup> Hockey Cup - Large
```

**Problem** ASP.NET detects this as a potentially unsafe string but of course this will never be so I tried to add this to the .aspx page directive:

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

**but it did not work**.  ASP.NET is still throwing the error:

A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (removedName="<sup>©</sup> Hockey...").

**Second**, does anyone pass Html like this in a querystring for completely harmful circumstances?  Meaning is this common?  And does it cause problems with passing strings with spaces via a querystring param or are spaces acceptable?

Comment: Could you pass the "removedName" though the Session object instead?

Comment: Ah what the hell am I thinking. I can just pass a different ID. You see I deleted a clone of an item.  But I can still pass the original itemID over querystring. Then get the name from the real item still in our system.  I don't need to pass the name of the deleted cloned item. (you prob have no clue what I'm talking about but it refers to our business).  Anyway, point is, try to find a way NOT to pass over what I'm trying to pass, especially like you said, HTML or stuff that will be reshown on the page as it's a big no no on string injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start by saying this is generally a bad idea. You don't want to give direct control of what is rendered in the page over to the user. They could put anything in the querystring. You're better off caching the message like so:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(id, "<sup>foo</sup>");
Response.Redirect("page.aspx?message=" + id.ToString());
```

And then retrieving the message (and if you want, removing it):

```
string message = HttpRuntime.Cache[new Guid(Request.QueryString["message"])];
HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(id);
```

But if you must need to know how to put HTML in the querystring:

Encode it:

```
string value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("<sup>foo</sup>");
```

Yields:

```
%3Csup%3Efoo%3C%2Fsup%3E
```

And decode to get the reverse:

```
string value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%3Csup%3Efoo%3C%2Fsup%3E");
```

Comment: good god,duh!  thanks man.  I have been using asp.net controls WAY WAY too much. Nice to get away from them and just use more redirects and request.

Comment: Sorry, -1. You should never pass HTML in a querystring.

Comment: @John never say never. I did add clarification.

Comment: I like the updated answer, but it says my downvote is too old to undo.

Comment: yea, did not work...6+Designs<sup>©<%2fsup>+Hockey+Mug++  ended up with that...mixed HTML and encoded values

Comment: @coffeeaddict are you sure? I'm definitely not seeing that. Just set up a test to verify.

Comment: I am positive: Response.Redirect(string.Format(Request.Path + "?ItemRemovedID={0}&removedName={1}", itemID, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Item.Name))) which resulted in a url in the .aspx after redirect of  ItemRemovedID=56&removedName=<sup>©<%2fsup>+Hockey+Coffee+Mug++

Answer (score 2):

Allowing HTML to be passed in a querystring is extremely dangerous and opens your site up to numerous security issues. You should find a way to pass some data (like an ID and message type) via the querystring (or even better, in the Session or a Cookie) and have the page you redirect to determine which message to show.

Comment: It would just be nice to encapsulate that removal of the item in my .ascx and handle showing that message all in the .ascx.cs. The problem is I have to do a redirect to refresh the page after the user clicks the hyperlink and then I have to remove that item and redirect to the same page to refresh. Because I have to redirect, I loose everything in code-behind so the only way would be to pass that through querystring such as the name of the item that was deleted.

Comment: Otherwise I'd have to setup a handler in my .ascx and handle the removal of the item in whatever .aspx pages that are using this control which is redundant code.  So I kept the remove logic in the .ascx.cs and it checks the querystring for the removedItemID after the user clicks the remove hyperlink in my .ascx and handles it from the .ascx.cs code behind.  I redirect to the Request.Page (whatever .aspx is using this control) so I need to also show a confirmation message right above my control that x item was removed on that .aspx page.  That message is set and shown at the top of my .ascx

Comment: Good answers. Thanks.  I wanted to give you both the answer but can't.